# url_for in an email sent by a rake task in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I have a rake task that sends out daily digest emails of player activity during a day. (See example code below.) If I run `PlayerActivityMailer.activity_report.deliver` in my console, everything works just fine. However, when I try to invoke the rake task, I get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
ActionView::Template::Error: arguments passed to url_for can't be handled.
Please require routes or provide your own implementation
```

After doing some research, I found that in Rails 4, they totally nerfed `ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper.url_for` (http://apidock.com/rails/v4.1.8/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/url_for - notice the giant red minus sign under the 4.0.2). If you look at the source, you can see the error I'm seeing - it no longer takes options. As far as I can tell, that functionality still exists in other `url_for`s, such as the one in `ActionDispatch::Routing::UrlFor`. Also, the error message suggests including `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers`.

**What I've tried**

- `include ActionDispatch::Routing::UrlFor` in both the rake task (inside the task) and the mailer (both at the same time, and each separately)
- `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` in the same places and configurations, both with and without the `UrlFor` include.

The error still persists. My guess is that the page view is still insisting on using the `ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper` version of `url_for`. I don't think I can include things actually in the views (which is sloppy looking and hacky even if I could).

**Example Code**
(heavily sanitized)

config/environtments/development.rb:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost:3000' }
```

lib/tasks/player.rake:

```
namespace :player do
  task :activity => :environment do
    PlayerActivityMailer.activity_report.deliver
  end
end
```

app/mailers/player_activity_mailer.rb:

```
class PlayerActivityMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def activity_report
    @activities = PlayerActivity.all
    mail(to: 'foo@bar.com', subject: 'activity report')
  end
end
```

app/views/player_activity_mailer/activity_report.html.erb:

```
<% @activites.each do |activity| %>
    Player: <%= link_to activity.player.name, player_url(id: activity.player.id) %>
    ...
<% end %>
```

I also have a model Player, `resources :players` in my routes.rb file, and a PlayerActivity class with an association to Player.

I'm currently using the (really horrifying) workaround of `@base_url = Rails.configuration.action_mailer.default_url_options[:host]` in my mailer action and `"http://#{@base_url}/players/#{activity.player.id}"` in my view instead of the player_url part.

Help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing just your player in the URL? Like this:

```
<% @activites.each do |activity| %>
    Player: <%= link_to activity.player.name, player_url(activity.player) %>
<% end %>
```